# How to access route parameter in custom validation rule laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5.3

How can I access route parameters in custom validation rule

Here's my code:

Route:

```
http://api.example.com/users/{user_id}/update
```

```php
Route::post('users/{user_id}/update', 'UserController@update')->name('user:update');
```

My custom validation rule:

```php
namespace App\Validators;

use Illuminate\Validation\Validator;

class Validators extends Validator
{
    public function __construct($translator,$data,$rules,$messages=[],$customAttributes=[])
    {
        parent::__construct($translator,$data,$rules,$messages,$customAttributes);
    }

    public function validateRole($attribute, $value, $rules)
    {
        // here I want to access the route parameters

        $user_id = $this->route('user_id');
    }
}
```

```php
namespace App\Api\V1\Requests\SectionMilestone;

use App\Api\ApiRequest;

class SectionMilestoneRequest extends ApiRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'teacher_id'    => 'required|role:school'
        ];
    }
}
```

If anybody knows how to accomplish this, please help me save some time.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you show your actual `Route` for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take it directly from the request object or use the public request() function for it.

```
public function validateRole($attribute, $value, $rules)
{

    $user_id = request()->route('user_id');
}
```